# Is there an equivalent of var_dump for methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, var-dump

I'm working on some legacy code and I need to get some information from an object. The price, for example. The price could be stored in a variable or it could be retrieved via a method. I don't yet know, only that it exists within the object.

I can grab an object in the code and var_dump all of the variables to have a look-see at what's available at that point in the runtime. But sometimes what I need isn't returned by

```
$item->price
```

but instead needs to be retrieved by

```
$item->get_price()
```

It seems to me it would be really helpful to be able to dump information from methods in the same way as I can dump information from variables.

So ideally I'd stick this command in the code, and it would return minimally a list of all methods that can be called on the object. Ideally, if those methods have no inputs, then it would also return their return values too.

Does such a command exist in PHP? In any language?

Comment: `get_class_methods` and class `Reflection`

Comment: Whatever you do, if the class has a magic `__call()` method, then you won't be able to identify any methods that might go into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own.

Take a look at [`get_class_methods`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php). You need to have the class name for this. You can obtain this by [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

So you want to introduce something like this in your library:

```
function getObjectMethods(object $obj) {
    $className = get_class($obj);
    return get_class_methods($className);
}
```

Maybe you should think about a better IDE, which supports type hinting etc. Take a look at [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) for example.

Comment: "Ideally, if those methods have no inputs, then it would also return their return values too." I think you are on a sligthly different track than op needs